# Can Online DQN model overfit?

Tags: overfitting, dqn, online-learning

I am new in the area of RL and currently trying to train an online DQN model. Can an online model overfit since its always learning? and how can I tell if that happens?

Answer (score 0):

Overfitting is a meaningful drop in performance between training and prediction. Any model can overfit. Online DQN model could continue with data over time but not make useful predictions.